# Is a graph an induced subgraph of itself?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

This might seem like a silly question, but I know that a graph is a subgraph of itself. Is it also true that a graph is an induced subgraph of itself?

Comment: Of course. It's the subgraph induced by the set of all vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the subgraph induced by taking all vertices of the original graph as your inducing subset.